# Cant configure existing samba share

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I am sorry for the probably dumb question. I have two Ubuntu server VMs - 12.10 and 13.10. A year ago I have configured samba on both machines somehow with *documents* share on each. Now I cannot find this configuration. That is both shares *work* but neither /var/samba/smb.conf nor system-config-samba shows them! If I stop smbd service - sharing stops working. Both boxes have a separate volume mounted inside home folder and shared with name "documents". Please help!

Comment: Both 12.10 and 13.10 are end of life so support on askubuntu has ended. But I would expect the samba config to be in /etc/. Do a `locate smb.conf`

Comment: I have just upgraded second VM to 14.04. Same result: `root@ubnt1404:~# locate smb.conf
/etc/samba/smb.conf
/usr/share/doc/nautilus-share/examples/smb.conf
<some examples skipped> /usr/share/man/man5/smb.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/samba/smb.conf
/usr/share/system-config-samba/smb.conf.template
/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:samba:smb.conf

root@ubnt1404:~# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | grep documents
root@ubnt1404:~#`

Comment: Close-voters: Since this is answered and the answer is valuable, upvoted, accepted, and applies to current Ubuntu releases equally, I don't think we need to close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we are dealing with usershares.

Those are stored in `/var/lib/samba/usershare`.

You can use the command [net](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/net.8.html) to manage them, ie:

```
net usershare add (name) (path)
net usershare delete (name)
net usershare list
```